# AS3: Overriding 'name' property of Error in subclass

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-errors

I'm trying to define a custom Error subclass in AS3 and would like to override the `name` property as I have some error handling code that logs errors based on the type (name).

```
package com.company {

    public class MyError extends Error {
        public function MyError() {
            super("Some description.");
        }

        // Error 1023: Incompatible override
        public override function get name():String { 
            return "MyError";
        }
    }

}
```

However I get "Error 2013: Incompatible override" on the `get name` override.

Does anyone know the correct syntax for this? As far as I can tell it seems correct based on the [name property in the Error class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html#name). The intended result is:

```
var e:Error = new MyError();
trace(e.name); // Should be "MyError"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` is defined as `public var name:String`. So it's a public property and no getter method is defined. So you can't override the getter. To change the name you can just assign your name after calling super's constructor.

```
public function MyError() {
    super("Some description.");
    name = "MyError";
}
```

Comment: I had tried that before but just realized my error was in putting the `name =` line before the `super()` call. Putting it after successfully overrode the name. Thanks!